# Lifecycle hook that is called after data-bound properties of a directive are initialized (ngOnInit)

Tags: javascript, angular

what does it mean "called after data-bound properties of a directive are initialized" in ngOnInit definition?

Comment: take a look `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367423/what-is-ata-bound-properties`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ata-bound properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367423/what-is-ata-bound-properties)

Answer (score 0):

ngOnInit is a life cycle hook called by Angular 2 to indicate that Angular is done creating the component.

We need to import OnInit in order to use like this (actually implementing OnInit is not mandatory but considered good practice):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
```

then to use the method of OnInit we have to implement in the class like this.

```
export class ClassName implements OnInit{
  constructor(){
     //called first time before the ngOnInit()
  }

  ngOnInit(){
     //called after the constructor and called  after the first ngOnChanges() 
  }
}
```

> ngOnInit is called right after the directive's data-bound properties
>   have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children
>   have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is
>   instantiated.

Please check this [Link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: What is "right after the directives' data-bound properties have been checked for the first time"?@sujeet