# Angular 6 private methods

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, private

We are upgrading to Angular 6 from 5.  We have a shared library that we are getting build errors.  Being a Java shop, we got in the habit of marking our component methods and attributes private.  In Angular 6 when building our library (after converting and using the new library CLI capability), we get:

```
Property 'getCurrentYear' is private and only accessible within class.
```

In effect any attribute or method used in a template html cannot be marked private anymore on the component class.  Of course we can fix this by removing the 'private' modifier.  This was not the case in angular 5 when we produced our library using https://github.com/raphael-volt/ng2-testable-lib.

Oddly enough, this ONLY happens when compiling our library.  We upgraded an app to angular 6 that also has private attributes and methods on the component / usage in template and no issues there.

Did we find a bug?  Is there a best practice we are not adhering to?

Comment: It needs to be public because of AOT compilation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Angular we have 2 models of compilation

- **JIT - Just-in-Time Compilation** : JIT compilation as the name implies, compiles the application Just-in-Time in the browser at
  runtime.
- **AoT - Ahead-of-Time Compilation :** AoT compilation compiles the application at build time.

By default, with the development build i.e `ng serve` we get JIT compilation. This is how it works. The application code along with the angular compiler is downloaded by the browser. At runtime, when a request is issued to the application, the JIT-compiler in the browser compiles the application code before it is executed.

with the production build i.e `ng build --prod` we get  AoT compilation the angular application is pre-compiled. So this means the browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the application first.

TypeScript `public` doesn't matter but `private` does

> **From Angular Docs**
>   All **[`data bound`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39367574/5695162)** properties must be TypeScript public
>   properties. Angular never binds to a TypeScript private property.

***Actually, it does bind to the `private` properties, but not in `AoT mode`***

**[`Why AOT Compiler requires public properties, while non-AOT allows private properties?`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11978)**

With JIT we convert all the code to ES5 and then at runtime, we do the bindings. All the visibility modifiers are lost in that process, so it doesn't matter if you say `public` or `private` for that.

On the other hand, with AoT, we generate some typescript code for our templates, that will try to access those fields. If they are `private`, they simply cannot access those properties, hence, you need to put them as `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Properites used in templaes must be public - this is connected with AoT compilation.

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler (find word "public" there)