# Angular dropdown image

Tags: angular, image, dropdown, html-select

i have array where we have image but when i call in html they dont show it but in inspect they show it

```
<div class="dropdown" *ngFor="let in of counter(inputCount); let ind = index">
    <select placeholder="Select" (change)="filterValue($event)" let i="index">
        <option *ngFor="let filter of filters ; let indexOfElement= index" [value]="indexOfElement">{{filter?.name}}<img src="{{filter?.icon}}"/></option>
    </select>
```

filters = [
{
name: 'Status',
icon: "../../../../assets/images/filters/screen.jpg",
values: [
{ status_kuid: '100', status_label: 'Todo' },
{ status_kuid: '101', status_label: 'In Progress' },
{ status_kuid: '102', status_label: 'Done' },
],
isApplied: false,
usedByField_index: '',
},

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802662/image-in-asset-folder-not-accessible-in-angular-application

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.