# Angular : How to access Form control which is inside Form Group from HTML

Tags: angular, contenteditable, angular-forms

I am trying to display form Control "name" in HTML

The Form control "name" is grouped inside form group : "sample"

Am not aware of hierarchy

Here is the HTML code :

```
<p contenteditable="true" [formControl]="name"> </p>

<div>
    FORM GROUP Value : {{ sample.value | json }}
    <br>
    FORM CONTROL VALUE : {{sample.value.name}}
</div>
```

HERE IS the TYPESCRIPT CODE :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ng-contenteditable-my-example1',
  templateUrl: './ng-contenteditable-my-example1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ng-contenteditable-my-example1.component.scss']
})
export class NgContenteditableMyExample1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private titleService: Title,
    private _router: Router) {
      this.titleService.setTitle('formbuilder');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // console.log("Sample Status : " + this.sample.status);
    this.sample.controls.name.setValue(`Ashish`)
  }

  sample : FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name : new FormControl(null,[Validators.nullValidator])
  });

}
```

I an getting this error :

```
NgContenteditableMyExample1Component.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
    at _throwError (forms.js:3357)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:3181)
    at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7102)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31906)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NgContenteditableMyExample1Component.html:23)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
```

Comment: You should either wrap the ‘input’ inside a formgroup sample or you could get the form control using [formControl]=“sample.get(‘name’)”

Comment: If you use a FormGroup, use a form and inside use formControlName="name", if only need a FormControl, you needn't create a FormGroup, create a simple FormControl: `name=new FormControl(null,Validators.nullValidator)`. BTW in Angular **not** exist Validators.nullValidator else Validators.required. read the doc: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

It is because `[formControl]="name"` is a [data-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367423/what-is-data-bound-properties) property, which means it will **look for** a **variable** called `name` in your **component class**. Because you don't have any, you will get that error.

You can fix this either by doing this `formControlName='name'` or `[formControlName]="'name'"`

Also, note that the `formControl` directive must refer to a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) instance, not to a **string** that maps to a `FormControl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a FormControl that's defined inside a FormGroup this way:

```
<p contenteditable="true" [formControl]="sample.get('name')"> </p>
```